# possible collapse/folding compound expression

Tags: php, syntax, phpstorm

I have the following code in which there is a simple compound expression.
This is done more for convenience, to allocate large blocks in procedural style ... I have no choice =(

what would don't comment the beginning of a large block of code and its completed. it is convenient to highlight that part of the compound expression, with the only comment at the beginning of the expression

Example:

```
<?
/*... some code*/
{
   /*... very many lines of dedicated code*/
}
/*... some code*/
?>
```

but, phpstorm don't folding it ...
although it would be very convenient ...

maybe there are some settings?

thanks

Comment: You need to **restructure the code** or you **need to fold**??

Comment: there is a CMS 1C-Bitrix ... it is almost entirely in the procedural style .... I have to adapt to it =( I need to fold this block in phpstorm ...

Comment: just for convenience ...
alternatively possible to use the following construction
if(1) {
    /*... very many lines of dedicated code*/
}
but as it is right?

Answer (score 2):

The combination you are looking for is `Ctrl`+`.` (press these after you select a code block)

After you collapse a certain block for the first time, you'll see the marks on the left so you can use those, instead of selecting the block again.

For all expanding/collapsing info read: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/folding-and-expanding-code-blocks.html

Comment: it is working only when using a block of construction: if, while, for, etc ...
I would like to use the blank blocks - pacifiers, no semantic load... 
echo 1; { echo 2; echo 3; } echo 4;  where blank blocks is  { echo 2; echo 3; } - he should folding

Comment: @Dmitriy Alex have suggested the right thing -- use **custom region folding** to fold any amount of lines, even if they do not have any logical structure. If not sure/having problems -- show screenshot with **real** code.

Comment: yes, yes, his advice is very helpful, and I did not know about it. but we are in fact a little bit about the other, you can certainly use a combination of CTRL +} and CTRL +. but perhaps there is a better way? it would be very convenient )) but apparently not ...

Comment: @Dmitry Other way for what? Can you be clear please?